# Customisation of RangeSelectors in highstock

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts

I want to customize the range & date selector in highstock chart library as shown in the proposed design.
I want to move Range Selector towards the bottom left & Date Selector towards bottom right and can we customize its look and feel as proposed in design?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the position of the Range Selectors based on the various combination of margin and position

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldktdwtv/) for demo

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
 marginBottom: 70 /*marign between chart area and bottom*/
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL stock price by minute'
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
            type: 'hour',
            count: 1,
            text: '1h'
        }, {
            type: 'day',
            count: 1,
            text: '1D'
        }, {
            type: 'all',
            count: 1,
            text: 'All'
        }],
        selected: 1,
        padding: 50,
    buttonPosition: {
            y: 360, /*Position of button from top*/
        },

    },
        navigator: {
         top:300, /*Postion of navigator from top*/
       },
    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL',
        type: 'candlestick',
        data: data,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is having hard coded value like 360 or 300 can we make it relative to the top of navigator? If we make it relative to another component it will be easy to manage the responsiveness of chart and can render it perfectly in the given area of chart rendering.

Comment: positioning option for both the navigator and the range selector  are not very dynamic  in api. So we have to  hard code it

Comment: I have found the solution to it, create your on range selector and use bootstrap date picker. It will become responsive & adapt the screen size.